# website shows unavailable while taking DB backup?

Tags: 7, database

My website is created using Drupal 7 on one instance of amazon & database is on amazon RDS . whenever i am taking backup of database using Mysql with root user & simultaneously when a developer try to clear the cache on the website that time website goes offline untill backup gets over say for around 30 min this happens everytime . what is the solution to avoid this problem . I am using inodb storage engine & using MYsql Administrator application to take backup with all tables selected.

Comment: Give your server more resources temporarily (processors/memory) - does the problem persist? If so, it's an app problem; if not, it's a resource problem